# How can I hide the tab bar for a single view controller in a navigation controller stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`. One of the tabs contains a `UINavigationController`.

I'd like to push a view controller onto the navigation stack and hide the tab bar on that view controller. I can do this easily with:

```
toVC.tabBarController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
```

or doing it in the storyboard:

[image: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed]

The problem is, this hides the tab bar for any subsequent view controllers I push onto the stack. I'd like to simply hide the tab bar for this one view controller and show it for all other view controllers before and after it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround. It works the way it is presented on gif below.

[image: the gif]

For each `UIViewController` that is pushed into the `UINavigationController` stack I `override` the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property this way:

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        switch navigationController?.topViewController {
        case .some(let controller):
            switch controller == self {
            case true:
                return super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
            case false:
                return false
            }
        default:
            return super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
        }
    }
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
}
```

The first `switch` checks whether this controller belongs to some `UINavigationController` stack. The second switch checks whether current top `UIViewController` of `UINavigationController` stack is `self`.

Hope it will work in your case. Happy coding (^

Comment: No need to override. A very simple solution is "destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;" where destinationViewController is the new controller that will be pushed.

Comment: @AbdulYasin I think you should post your comment as a answer

Answer (score 0):

If you hide on the storyboard then by this property your tab bar will hide for all the view controllers. So you can manage this by code.

You can do this programmatically by just writing one line of code in ViewDidLoad() or ViewWillAppear() method

For Swift 3:-

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

And where you want to unhide the tab bar just write the following code in ViewDidLoad () or ViewWillAppear() method

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

Comment: This just leaves a black bar where the tab bar once was.

Comment: Hey @JustinVallely, how did you fix that black bar at the bottom of the view?

Comment: This was 3+ years ago so I don't quite remember. I don't think I ever did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the view controller you want to hide the tab bar in:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

And this in the view controllers before and after the one you want to hide the tab bar in:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

**EDIT:**

Fully implemented example:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This just leaves a black bar where the tab bar once was.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure why you would be seeing a black bar. I updated my answer with an example and a gif showing it working. Maybe you can compare your implementation against the sample code? Also, what iOS version and device are you using to test?